# React Cannot read property of undefined - Array.map (<anonymous>)

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks, react-props, array.prototype.map

I am fetching data from api and importing the data in the WeatherData.js and passing it as a prop to SmallWeatherCard.js because I want to pass it to another component too later on.

when I do console.log(data) in SmallWeatherCard.js I can see the whole data in the console but when trying to map it I get an error "Cannot read property of undefined"

What am I doing wrong here?

all the code here: [Codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-ramanujan-yn3iq?file=/src/components/SmallWeatherCard.js)

```
import React from "react";

export const SmallWeatherCard = ({ data }) => {

  return (
    <div>
      {data.properties.timeseries.map((i, index) => (
        <div>
          <ul key={index}>
            <li> {i.data.next_6_hours.summary.symbol_code}
             </li>
            <li>
              {Math.round(i.data.next_6_hours.details.air_temperature_min)}°
            </li>
            <li>|</li>
            <li>
              {Math.round(i.data.next_6_hours.details.air_temperature_max)}°
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: How are u using the `SmallWeatherCard` component? the component isn't used in sandbox and i see no errors

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Answer (score 0):

Your probably using [this kinda](https://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/2.0?lat=59.93&lon=10.72&altitude=90) api. So, the error is api doesn't always return all fields. For example in my case `i.data.next_6_hours` wasn't defined.

So, try something like this,

```
export const SmallWeatherCard = ({ data }) => {
  console.log(typeof data);

  return (
    <div>
      {data.properties.timeseries.map(
        (i, index) =>
          i.data.next_6_hours != null && (
            <div>
              <ul key={index}>
                <li>
                  {Math.round(i.data.next_6_hours.details.air_temperature_min)}°
                </li>
                <li>|</li>
                <li>
                  {Math.round(i.data.next_6_hours.details.air_temperature_max)}°
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          )
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Using [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-diffie-6y4dc).